# log4j2 confguration file location when using jetty maven plugin

Tags: log4j, jetty, log4j2, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

My application uses log4j2 and we have two of them one for production and another for development environment. I am using maven to run the application using `mvn clean jetty:run`. My plugin configuration in `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
              <name>log4j.configuration</name>
              <value>${log4j-dev.location}</value>
            </systemProperty>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

But my app still uses the `log4j2.xml` present in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory instead of the one in the `log4j-dev.location` path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. In the `webdefault.xml` file, I had to add the following code:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
  <param-value>log4j2-custom.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Hope it helps somebody who spent a whole day looking everywhere like me :)